# Clicking on a Javascript Link on Firefox with Selenium

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I am trying to get some comments off the car blog, [Jalopnik](http://jalopnik.com/5912009/prius-driver-beat-up-after-taking-out-two-bikers).  It doesn't come with the web page initially, instead the comments get retrieved with some Javascript.  You only get the featured comments.  I need all the comments so I would click "All" (between "Featured" and "Start a New Discussion") and get them.

To automate this, I tried learning Selenium.  I modified [their script](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) from Pypi, guessing the code for clicking a link was `link.click()` and `link = broswer.find_element_byxpath(...)`.  It doesn't look liek the "All" button (displaying all comments) was pressed.

Ultimately I'd like to download the HTML of that version to parse.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://jalopnik.com/5912009/prius-driver-beat-up-after-taking-out-two-bikers/") # Load page
time.sleep(0.2)

link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='tc cn_showall']")
link.click()
browser.save_screenshot('screenie.png')
browser.close()
```

Comment: updated my code with Python version, if you still interested in it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Firefox with the Firebug plugin, I browsed to `http://jalopnik.com/5912009/prius-driver-beat-up-after-taking-out-two-bikers`.

I then opened the Firebug console and clicked on ALL; it obligingly showed a single AJAX call to `http://jalopnik.com/index.php?op=threadlist&post_id=5912009&mode=all&page=0&repliesmode=hide&nouser=true&selected_thread=null`

Opening that url in a new window gets me the comment feed you are seeking.

More generally, if you substitute the appropriate article-ID into that url, you should be able to automate the process without Selenium.

Comment: Yep. Don't try to automate a browser; figure out where the scripts are getting their information and grab it from there.

Comment: In the html page it just said `<a href='#' ... >` and I had no idea where # was pointing to.

Comment: @john mangual: yep, that's why Firebug is so helpful - instead of tracing through the source code to figure out what it will do, just watch what it does!

Comment: For the record, when you see an `href='#'` that often means that the link will be handled by a script. That's when you break out the Web console in Firefox.