# Parsing web page containing dynamic javascript objects

Tags: java, python, parsing, htmlunit, dynamic-content

Currently I'm using python and its urllib2, urllib to retrieve a simple static web page. Everything was smooth until web-page developers added java scripts. Now the most interesting information is hidden behind the scripts:

```
<a href="javascript://" class="event-more-view" id="view-moreid-12311" onclick="Markets.applyView(this);return false;" treeid="1291266" eventstate ="false" > add table </a>
```

Browser preloads data and shows it when the "a href" link is clicked.
The results of my short research are JSOUP and HTMLunit. Am I digging in a right direction? Any cons and pros?

Will python help? Should I be using Java? What packages can help with dynamic content? What is simpler?

In my case I have to create some sort of a virtual browser as far as built-in scripts refresh data over time which has to be processed.

Answer (score 2):

You are digging in a right direction.

Here are some options/tools to consider:

- [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/)
- [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) under jython
- [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

See also:

- [Click on a javascript link within python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207948/click-on-a-javascript-link-within-python)
- [Simulating clicking on a javascript link in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436418/simulating-clicking-on-a-javascript-link-in-python)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Looking in to these packages... What about Ruby and Watir?