# How to use Selenium to interact with javascript in python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

First I use python and selenium to load a website in firefox. Then I fill in a simple javascript type form. The site is poorly made but usually if I tell selenium to use (Keys.RETURN) then it will drop down a list of options. The problem is I don't know how to click on one of these because they didn't load with the web page. I tried using (Keys.ARROW_DOWN) to go through them but it still doesn't really work.

How can I interact with javascript through selenium using python?

Thanks.

P.S. I know almost nothing about javascript so if there is some way to do it, I still would be clueless on how to use javascript anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You might have to tell the browser to wait for a few milliseconds.

Some places to look:

[Clicking on a Javascript Link on Firefox with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018796/clicking-on-a-javascript-link-on-firefox-with-selenium)

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp